# SQL Server Access to Disk C

Tags: sql-server, excel, windows, stored-procedures, openrowset

Is there any way to grant my SQL Authenticated SQL Server Account a Full Control access to Disk C? I have an Excel File uploader that opens .xlsx files to read the data and INSERT it into the database. My server is located on Disk C and that's also where I copy the files being uploaded by the user before I open it systematically.

As of now, I am having the

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

error using my SQL Authenticated account because the file is in Disk C but when I use my Windows Authenticated account it works fine. What I want to achieve is that my SQL Authenticated account should have the same level of access in the server as my SQL Authenticated Account so that my uploader can upload just fine even if I'm using an SQL Authenticated Account.

Comment: Your SQL Server "service" account does of course have very restricted access, as should all service accounts. Why don't you just put the files into a folder where the service does have access?

Comment: But you can of course grant the service account access to whatever you want.

Comment: Given that access permissions tend to propagate into subfolders you almost certainly don't want to grant SQL Server Full Control access of C:\ because you're effectively giving it carte blanche access to the whole C: drive. Don't you have a commonly accessible temp folder somewhere?

Comment: Better idea: use something like Powershell or a VBA script to open the file and bulk insert it. Using `OPENROWSET` or linked servers on the ACE provider is not properly supported anyway.